# Fill space with dots within table

Tags: tables, xetex, booktabs

I would like the whitespace between two items within a table to be filled with dots. 
Please consider the following picture to get the idea.

[image: whitespace filled with dots]

So far I tried to achieve this output with the following sequence.

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]

\begin{tabular}{lrrr}
        \toprule
    Anzahl & Behandlungstyp & Einzelpreis & Gesamtpreis\\
        \midrule
    10\dotfill& Manuelle Therapie\dotfill & €32,63\dotfill & €326,30\\
    10\dotfill &Krankengymastik\dotfill &€26,93\dotfill &€269,30\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This, however, yields an unsatisfactory output, where undotted gaps are left over.
[image: output]

How to achieve a continuous dotted line without white spaces like in the first picture?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an ugly hack

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]

\begin{tabular}{l@{}r@{}lr}
 \toprule
    Anzahl \quad 
    & \multicolumn{1}{r@{}}{\hspace{1cm}Behandlungstyp}\quad  
    & Einzelpreis  
    & Gesamtpreis\\
 \midrule
    10\dotfill 
    & Manuelle Therapie\dotfill
    &\multicolumn{2}{@{}c}{€32,63\dotfill  €326,30}\\
    %%
    10\dotfill 
    & Krankengymastik\dotfill  
    &\multicolumn{2}{@{}c}{€26,93\dotfill €269,30}\\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}    
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the alignment as requested in the comment

```
\begin{tabular}{lcr@{}r@{}r}
 \toprule
    Anzahl
    &
    & Behandlungstyp  
    & \multicolumn{1}{@{\hspace{1em}}r@{}}{Einzelpreis}
    & \multicolumn{1}{@{\hspace{1em}}r}{Gesamtpreis}\\
 \midrule
    \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{10\dotfill Manuelle Therapie}
    & \dotfill 32,63
    & \dotfill 326,30\\
    %%
    \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{10\dotfill Krankengymastik}
    & \dotfill 26,93
    & \dotfill 269,30\\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: If we could just manage to align the items correctly this hack would be easy to use.

Comment: @Ray What is your idea of "aligning the items correctly"? Do you mean to align the header of the second column and entries in the second column (let us say on the left)?

Comment: The alignment should actually be '{lrrr}'. If you take a look at the items of the second column, you will notice that they are everything else but right aligned - same applies for the items of the third column. The items of the first and last column are, however, correctly aligned.

Answer (score 7):

I believe that you need only the `@{}` separator and  `p{}` columns with `\dotfill` or `\hfill` in the cells.

On the other hand, I lost the € symbol with your MWE because the lack of the `fontspec` package. For comparison, I included also the `eurosym` package for more official symbol (showed in the third column).

[image: MWE]

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} % needed for the € symbol
\usepackage{eurosym} % another way to obtain the € symbol 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\begin{tabular}{p{.4\textwidth}@{}p{.2\textwidth}@{}p{.2\textwidth}@{}}
\toprule
Anzahl \hfill Behandlungstyp & \hfill Einzelpreis & \hfill Gesamtpreis\\
\midrule
10\dotfill  Manuelle Therapie & \dotfill\euro32,63 & \dotfill€326,30\\
10\dotfill  Krankengymastik & \dotfill\euro26,93 &\dotfill€269,30\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are two options:

1. Manual using box length calculations:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
   \newlength{\tmplenA}\newlength{\tmplenB}
   \begin{document}

   \begin{tabular}{lrrr}
     \toprule
     Anzahl & Behandlungstyp & Einzelpreis & Gesamtpreis\\
     \midrule
     \settowidth{\tmplenA}{Anzahl}\settowidth{\tmplenB}{10}\addtolength{\tmplenA}{-\tmplenB}%
     10\rlap{\makebox[\dimexpr\tmplenA+2\tabcolsep][l]{\dotfill}} & Manuelle Therapie 
     & \settowidth{\tmplenA}{Einzelpreis}\settowidth{\tmplenB}{€32,63}\addtolength{\tmplenA}{-\tmplenB}%
     \llap{\makebox[\dimexpr\tmplenA+2\tabcolsep][r]{\dotfill}}€32,63 
     & \settowidth{\tmplenA}{Gesamtpreis}\settowidth{\tmplenB}{€326,30}\addtolength{\tmplenA}{-\tmplenB}%
     \llap{\makebox[\dimexpr\tmplenA+2\tabcolsep][r]{\dotfill}}€326,30 \\
     \settowidth{\tmplenA}{Anzahl}\settowidth{\tmplenB}{10}\addtolength{\tmplenA}{-\tmplenB}%
     \settowidth{\tmplenB}{Manuelle Therapie}\addtolength{\tmplenA}{\tmplenB}%
     \settowidth{\tmplenB}{Krankengymastik}\addtolength{\tmplenA}{-\tmplenB}%
     10\rlap{\makebox[\dimexpr\tmplenA+2\tabcolsep][l]{\dotfill}} & Krankengymastik
     & \settowidth{\tmplenA}{Einzelpreis}\settowidth{\tmplenB}{€26,93}\addtolength{\tmplenA}{-\tmplenB}%
     \llap{\makebox[\dimexpr\tmplenA+2\tabcolsep][r]{\dotfill}}€26,93 
     & \settowidth{\tmplenA}{Gesamtpreis}\settowidth{\tmplenB}{€269,30}\addtolength{\tmplenA}{-\tmplenB}%
     \llap{\makebox[\dimexpr\tmplenA+2\tabcolsep][r]{\dotfill}}€269,30\\
     \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}

   \end{document}​
   ```
2. Overwriting a `\dotfill` spanning the entire `tabular` width with white-background-boxed entries:

   ```
   \documentclass{article}
   \usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
   \usepackage{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
   \usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
   \makeatletter
   \newcolumntype{L}{>{\begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}}l<{\end{lrbox}\colorbox{white}{\usebox{\@tempboxa}}}}
   \newcolumntype{R}{>{\begin{lrbox}{\@tempboxa}}r<{\end{lrbox}\colorbox{white}{\usebox{\@tempboxa}}}}
   \makeatother
   \newlength{\tmplenA}
   \setlength{\fboxrule}{0pt}\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
   \begin{document}

   \settowidth{\tmplenA}{AnzahlManuelleTherapieEinzelpreisGesamtpreis\hspace*{6\tabcolsep}}
   \begin{tabular}{LRRR}
     \toprule
     Anzahl & Behandlungstyp & Einzelpreis & Gesamtpreis\\
     \midrule
     \rlap{\makebox[\tmplenA][l]{\dotfill}}\colorbox{white}{10} & Manuelle Therapie & €32,63 & €326,30 \\
     \rlap{\makebox[\tmplenA][l]{\dotfill}}\colorbox{white}{10} & Krankengymastik & €26,93 & €269,30\\
     \bottomrule
   \end{tabular}
   \end{document}​
   ```

Here's the output of both:

[image]

Comment: The first method works, but is very untransparent for me to be comprehensible - pardon this. The second one is indeed nice, but as you take a look at your output you will see that the dots are chopped. When I use my font they are even more chopped: http://cl.ly/image/2e3d2S1k3M3I Is there a possibility to make the first method easier, or make the second one more precise? Thank you.