# Period Padding with Price

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting

I'm looking for a way to have automated period padding for some items I'm discussing in my proposal. For example:

Pneumatic Drill.......................$450.12

Drill Bit.....................................$12.90

---

Ideally, I'm looking for something like the following I suppose:

`\noindent\hspace{0.45cm}\dag\hspace{0.25cm}\begin{period-padder}\$450.12\end{period-padder}`

Comment: I want the price to be nice and flush to the right margin. The items are indented using `\noindent\hspace{0.45cm}\dag\hspace{0.25cm}`.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Fill space with dots within table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/73412/5764)

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73412/fill-space-with-dots-within-table is related, but not duplicated.

Answer (score 3):

You can use de `\dotfill`command

```
Pneumatic Drill\dotfill \$45.12

Drill Bit\dotfill \$12.90
```

Comment: @BizSux Please click on the check mark on the left in order to accept this as an answer. Thanks. pablos you might edit your answer in order to provide a full MWE.