# split inside flalign

Tags: align, split, flalign

I am currently using split inside the align environment similar to the following example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
a1 & = 3534534343 \\
a2 & = 2342342  \\
a3 & = 4564564  \\
a4 & = 5845645645864596464  \\
a5 & = 345354  \\
a6 & = 1  
\end{split}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

However I would like to have all these equations flushed to the left along with the property that there is single numbering for the system of equations (this is the reason for using the split). I can use the flalign environment without split but it gives numbering to all the individual equations

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
a1 & = 3534534343 & \\
a2 & = 2342342  \\
a3 & = 4564564  \\
a4 & = 5845645645864596464  \\
a5 & = 345354  \\
a6 & = 1  
\end{flalign}
\end{document}
```

I am unable to use the split inside flalign as it gives me an error. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: If you are attempting to add more `&` inside the splitm, then no, `split` only allows up to one `&` per row. There is no build in inner companion  for flalign` like there is for `align` and `gather`. Perhaps you should try and explain exactly what it is you are trying to do and why you'll need `flalign` for that? I all the books I've setup I have never once used `flalign`.

Comment: I want to have a single numbering for all the equations. Is there a way to do it other than split? I just want everything the same as the first MWE just all the equations to the left instead of centered.

Comment: But why `flalign`? IMO it is much less readable than `align`

Comment: How else can I flush a set of aligned equations to the left? I actually hate using the flalign environment and really like the align environment but I dont know how to flush all these equations on the left within align

Comment: Other display formulas in the document should remain centered and only this one set flush left, or is it that you'd like to have *all* display formulas flush left?

Comment: Do you like to align to left text border all equation in your document or just this particular equation. In the later case can the `nccmath` package offer a solution.

Comment: Just this particular one. I do not want all equations in my document to be left aligned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not very clear what you like to achieve, but the following solution may help you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{fleqn} % defined in nccmath
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
a1 & = 3534534343 \\
a2 & = 2342342  \\
a3 & = 4564564  \\
a4 & = 5845645645864596464  \\
a5 & = 345354  \\
a6 & = 1
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}
\lipsum[12]
\[
c^2 = a^2 + b^2
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Environment `\begin{flegn} ... \end{fleqn}` (defined in `nccmath` package) locally align equation to the left (as do `amsmath` option `fleqn` for whole document).

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that fleqn was so flexible. I can even use align within fleqn

Comment: +1. :-) About [your earlier answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/502892/5001) that involved `\hdotfill`: I apologize profusely for not being much clearer. I was actually offering to [delete my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/502915/5001) if you wanted to take its main ideas on board yourself. So sorry for not being sufficiently. Please reconsider your delete decision.

Comment: @Mico, I know, and it is ok. I'm on vacation (and my brain too ;-) so I'm very relaxing (read lazy) now, so I look site not very serious, when other member of family have siesta :-)

Comment: @Zarko - By all means, have a wonderful, relaxing summer vacation.

Comment: @Zarko happy vacations btw!

Answer (score 7):

You should be aware that `flalign` stands for ***full length align*** and not for *flush left align*.

As such, `split` doesn't really make sense inside it.

You can emulate `split` using `aligned`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-3]
\begin{flalign}
\begin{aligned}
a1 & = 3534534343 \\
a2 & = 2342342  \\
a3 & = 4564564  \\
a4 & = 5845645645864596464  \\
a5 & = 345354  \\
a6 & = 1
\end{aligned}&&
\end{flalign}
\lipsum[2][1-3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

On the other hand, I see no reason for some displays to be flush left and others centered.

Comment: Off-topic. First time I see a bold italized text from one of your answers. Glad to see it!